# How to Sort Array of Object having Maps as properties ,on the basis of given Keys for Maps in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, oop, lambda

I am having a class
Suppose

```
class MyClass{
  String uniqueID;
  Map<String,Double> ranks; 
}
```

the ranks will contain different keys associated with different values for eg-

```
[{ UniqueID:"1",{{"OverAll":1.8},{"SumAll":"2.1"},{"DelAll":"2.1"}}},
{ UniqueID:"2",{{"OverAll":1.2},{"SumAll":"4.1"},{"DelAll":"6.1"}}},
{ UniqueID:"3",{{"OverAll":1.91},{"SumAll":"1.1"},{"DelAll":"6.1"}}},
{ UniqueID:"5",{{"OverAll":1.1},{"SumAll":"0.1"},{"DelAll":"9.1"}}}]
```

I want to sort the above objects by any given key like Sort by "OverAll" key in descending order.

```
ArrayListObject.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(p->p.ranks.get("OverAll")));
```

I have used above comparator but not giving me results ,anyone please suggest any solution.

Note-The key to sort by can be any provided key present in Hashmap .

Answer (score 0):

To begin  with, you should assign the keys to constants to make sure the program and the programmer never get it wrong. It is just a good practice, though.

```
final String OVER_ALL = "OverAll";
// etc.
```

Another important thing to notice is that you can't fill the values of the `Map` with `String`, if the value class is explicitly `Double`. So this should be your list:

```
[{ UniqueID:"1", {{"OverAll":1.8},  {"SumAll":2.1}, {"DelAll":2.1}} },
 { UniqueID:"2", {{"OverAll":1.2},  {"SumAll":4.1}, {"DelAll":6.1}} },
 { UniqueID:"3", {{"OverAll":1.91}, {"SumAll":1.1}, {"DelAll":6.1}} },
 { UniqueID:"5", {{"OverAll":1.1},  {"SumAll":0.1}, {"DelAll":9.1}} } ]
```

Now, since you want to order the list in descending order, this should be the comparator to use:

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = (mc1, mc2) ->
    Double.compare(mc2.ranks.get(OVER_ALL), mc1.ranks.get(OVER_ALL));
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is the class that implements [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface. You want an implementation that can handle an arbitrary string from the `ranks` map (in class `MyClass`) and you also want to be able to sort both ascending or descending. Here is my implementation.

```java
class MyClassComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {

    /** true means sort ascending. */
    private boolean ascending;

    /** 'ranks' map key to sort by. */
    private String key;

    public MyClassComparator(String key, boolean ascending) {
        this.key = key;
        this.ascending = ascending;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        Double d1 = o1.getRanks().get(key);
        Double d2 = o2.getRanks().get(key);
        return ascending ? Double.compare(d1, d2) : Double.compare(d2, d1);
    }
}
```

Note that the above code does no error checking, for example if `getRanks()` returns null or if `get()` returns null.

Now the `MyClass` class with a `main()` method for testing.

```java
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass {
    private String  uniqueID;
    private Map<String, Double>  ranks;

    public MyClass(String uniqueID, Map<String, Double> ranks) {
        this.uniqueID = uniqueID;
        this.ranks = ranks;
    }

    public String getUniqueID() {
        return uniqueID;
    }

    public Map<String, Double> getRanks() {
        return ranks;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s: %s", uniqueID, ranks);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Double> map1 = Map.of("OverAll", 1.8, "SumAll", 2.1, "DelAll", 2.1);
        Map<String, Double> map2 = Map.of("OverAll", 1.2, "SumAll", 4.1, "DelAll", 6.1);
        Map<String, Double> map3 = Map.of("OverAll", 1.91, "SumAll", 1.1, "DelAll", 6.1);
        Map<String, Double> map4 = Map.of("OverAll", 1.1, "SumAll", 0.1, "DelAll", 9.1);
        List<MyClass> list = List.of(new MyClass("1", map1),
                                     new MyClass("2", map2),
                                     new MyClass("3", map3),
                                     new MyClass("5", map4));
        List<MyClass> sortedList = list.stream()
                                       .sorted(new MyClassComparator("OverAll", false))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
        sortedList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The `main()` method creates a `List` of `MyClass` objects using the sample data from your question. Note that method [of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-) (in class `java.util.Map`) was added in JDK 9, as was method `of()` in class `java.util.LIst`. Then it sorts the list in descending order according to the *OverAll* key. Just change the arguments in the call to the constructor of class `MyClassComparator` to get different sorts. Running the above code gives the following output.

```
3: {DelAll=6.1, OverAll=1.91, SumAll=1.1}
1: {DelAll=2.1, OverAll=1.8, SumAll=2.1}
2: {DelAll=6.1, OverAll=1.2, SumAll=4.1}
5: {DelAll=9.1, OverAll=1.1, SumAll=0.1}
```